# DateAdd is not updated in iteration

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Good day everyone, I have a problem I am working on a manufacturing planner for projects where I have a TextBox1 for the start date and a TextBox4 for the number of reels = Ci, the user must specify how many Ci (Reels) will be and starting from there start the planning of the manufacturing program.

All this information is emptied into a DataGridView where I have columns where the "Department" is "Section" "Operation" "End date" "Initial date"

The problem is when my code starts with Reel No 2, it assigns me the same dates calculated for Reel No 1, something like that.

```
Manufacturing   Channel Cut plate C1            04/07/2019  04/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Rolled plate C1         04/07/2019  04/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Longituidal welding C1  08/07/2019  09/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Re rolled C1            10/07/2019  11/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Cut plate C2            04/07/2019  04/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Rolled plate C2         04/07/2019  04/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Longituidal welding C2  08/07/2019  09/07/2019
Manufacturing   Chanel  rolled C2               10/07/2019  11/07/2019
```

I need the Reel of the C2 to start from the date of the last activity of Reel 1 and stay, something like that.

```
Manufacturing   Channel Cut plate C1            04/07/2019  04/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Rolled plate C1         05/07/2019  05/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Longituidal welding C1  06/07/2019  07/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Re rolled C1            10/07/2019  11/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Cut plate C2            11/07/2019  12/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Rolled plate C2         13/07/2019  14/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Longituidal welding C2  15/07/2019  16/07/2019
Manufacturing   Chanel  rolled C2               17/07/2019  18/07/2019
```

The code I was working with is the next.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click (sender As Object, and As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       Dim date1 As Date = CType (TextBox1.Text, Date)
        Dim numRows As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse (TextBox4.Text, numRows) Then
        If (numRows> = 1) Then
        For i As Integer = 1 To numRows
        Table.Rows.Add ("Manufacturing", "Channel", "Cut plate C" & i, DateAdd (DateInterval.Day, 1, date1), DateAdd (DateInterval.Day, 2, date1))
        Table.Rows.Add ("Manufacturing", "Channel", "Rolled plate C" & i, DateAdd (DateInterval.Day, 3, date1), DateAdd (DateInterval.Day, 4, date1))
        Table.Rows.Add ("Manufacturing", "Channel", "Longituid welding C" & i, DateAdd (DateInterval.Day, 5, date1), DateAdd (DateInterval.Day, 6, date1))
        Table.Rows.Add ("Manufacturing", "Channel", "Re rolled C" & i, DateAdd (DateInterval.Day, 7, date1), DateAdd (DateInterval.Day, 8, date1))
        Next
        Else
        MessageBox.Show ("Value:" & TextBox4.Text, "The number of rows must be greater than or equal to 1")
        End If
        Else
        MessageBox.Show ("Value:" & TextBox4.Text, "Invalid number")
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to explain in more detail how you want the days to change for each iteration of "i".   Maybe show a couple sets of rows?

Comment: @Idle_Mind  I want is like this.
Manufacturing Channel Cut plate C1 04/07/2019 04/07/2019
Manufacturing Channel Rolled plate C1 04/07/2019 04/07/2019
Manufacturing Channel Longituidal welding C1 08/07/2019 09/07/2019
Manufacturing Channel Re rolled C1 10/07/2019 11/07/2019
Manufacturing Channel Cut plate C2 11/07/2019 12/07/2019
Manufacturing Channel Rolled plate C2 13/07/2019 14/07/2019
Manufacturing Channel Longituidal welding C2 15/07/2019 16/07/2019
Manufacturing Chanel rolled C2 17/07/2019 18/07/2019
when the new activity begins Ci continue with the dates but I put the duration

Comment: I edited your original post with the rows of data.  It's still unclear to me what needs to happen.  Please explain what is correct, and what is incorrect in those rows.  Be specific!

Comment: @Idle_Mind my code with DateAdd RETURNS the date of C1 in C2, but does NOT update.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I edited my post and I try be specific, regards thx for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much better post after you edited it.

You said:

> I need the Reel of the C2 to start from the date of the last activity
>   of Reel 1 ...

You can change the value of "date1" at the bottom of the loop, so that the next reel starts with that date:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To numRows
    Table.Rows.Add("Manufacturing", "Channel", "Cut plate C" & i, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, date1), DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 2, date1))
    Table.Rows.Add("Manufacturing", "Channel", "Rolled plate C" & i, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 3, date1), DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 4, date1))
    Table.Rows.Add("Manufacturing", "Channel", "Longituid welding C" & i, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 5, date1), DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 6, date1))
    Table.Rows.Add("Manufacturing", "Channel", "Re rolled C" & i, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 7, date1), DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 8, date1))
    date1 = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 8, date1)
Next
```